# Localstack Docker outputting text about Python and Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, localstack

I tried to run the latest Localstack Docker using the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  localstack:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-localstack
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - PERSISTENCE=${PERSISTENCE-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - SERVICES=s3
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

What I'm getting is the following output:

```
Python 3.9.15 (main, Oct 13 2022, 23:42:12)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

This is certainly not what is expected, which is text about setting up the Localstack environment.

I tried version 1.2.0 and 1.1.0 as well, they show the same output. Interestingly, once the Python/Linux text appears, it also breaks this docker run command, taken from the documentation (it starts displaying the same output):

```
docker run --rm -it -p 4566:4566 -p 4510-4559:4510-4559 localstack/localstack
```

Here's the output for `docker info`:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.9.1)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.10.2)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.9)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.19.0)

Server:
 Containers: 18
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 18
 Images: 19
 Server Version: 20.10.17
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 9cd3357b7fd7218e4aec3eae239db1f68a5a6ec6
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.10.124-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 7.773GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: 4RM2:NCLZ:PMF3:PIEQ:TAUV:UCMP:6ZVB:27WV:U2M4:YUMU:6Z3A:TTTQ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 50
  Goroutines: 58
  System Time: 2022-10-22T13:43:10.684344556Z
  EventsListeners: 5
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what's the output of `docker info` in your local ?

Comment: hmm weird.. something is wrong in your env maybe, but I'm not sure

Comment: @GujaratSantana I edited my question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My localstack file had a custom build context, looks like that's causing the issue.

Change docker-compose.yml to the following (thank you, Harsh from the Localstack team):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53"                # DNS config (only required for Pro)
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"            # DNS config (only required for Pro)
      - "127.0.0.1:443:443"              # LocalStack HTTPS Gateway (only required for Pro)
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - PERSISTENCE=${PERSISTENCE-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - LOCALSTACK_API_KEY=${LOCALSTACK_API_KEY-}  # only required for Pro
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

After that:

- delete the localstack image (either using `docker image rm`), or via Docker Desktop (Images tab/hover over the localstack image/click on the 3 dots/click on Delete)
- run `docker-compose up --build`

If you need to run commands after building, execute them in a second helper container that depends on the main one.